# Putting a password in a REST API call

Tags: rest, passwords

Suppose I have a REST API that is also used to set/reset passwords. Let's also suppose that this works over a HTTPS connections. Is there any good reason not to put that password in the call path, let's also say I will encode it in BASE64?

An example would be to reset a password like this:

```
http://www.example.com/user/joe/resetpassword/OLDPASSWD/NEWPASSWD
```

I understand BASE64 is no encryption, but I only want to protect the password to shoulder surfing in this case.

Comment: Are you suggesting side effects on GET? That is a protocol violation right there.

Comment: This is not really REST because `resetpassword/OLDPASSWD/NEWPASSWD` is not a resource. It's an invocation of a process. You don't need to stuff everything into a URL.

Comment: @Esben: who said it's a GET? The OP never said that.

Comment: True, he didn't in the question. But his comment to Netch's answer says "Guess I'll have to use POST after all", so we can assume that he originally intended/asked about GET. Which, as Esben points out is A Bad Thing. GET should read only.

Comment: This [insightful article explaining many pitfalls of password reset mechanisms](http://www.troyhunt.com/2012/05/everything-you-ever-wanted-to-know.html) could possibly help understand the case better.

Comment: @arnaud I deduced it like Mawg explained.

Comment: By the way: Please be aware that many users re-use passwords for many different services. So if you don't protect your users passwords properly, and someone manages to retrieve a load of passwords of your users, he can do big harm to your users, even if your service isn't that sensitive.

Answer (score 81, accepted):

A good server logs all requests sent to it, including URLs (often, without variable part after '?'), source IP, execution time...  Do you really want this log (potentially read by a wide group of admins) to contain critically secure info as passwords? Base64 isn't a stopper against them.

Comment: This is not the biggest reason for using POST. It's a security reason. But as Esben allready note din the comments, changing state with a GET is a violation of such a Rest service

Comment: @BartFriederichs: and browser history would remember the URL. And trying out a bunch of password anonymously by making a web page that has a link for all the passwords you want to try, and letting Googlebot do the actual requests...

Comment: "But as Esben allready note din the comments, changing state with a GET is a violation of such a Rest service"  I noticed that comment, too, but I don't see where anyone's saying that this was a GET request.  You can embed information in a URI and still POST it, after all.  It's not really *RESTful*, though, since the URI isn't actually naming a resource.

Comment: Hi, good answer, but I disagree with the *"without variable part after '?'"* ...there are many many which store the full URL !!!

Comment: @jushua It was mainly the comment from OP "I'll guess I'll have to use post after all", that made my ask if he was using GET.

Comment: "changing state with a GET is a violation of such a Rest service" -- Let's not get too caught up in REST. Changing state with a GET is a violation of *HTTP*.

Answer (score 76):

What you are proposing is neither secure nor RESTful.

@Netch has already mentioned the issue with logs, but there is also another issue in that you are showing passwords being sent by HTTP, making it trivial to capture passwords with any sort of wire sniffer or man-in-the-middle attack.

When you do a GET request using REST, the different elements in the URL represent more fine grained elements.  Your URL reads like you are returning a NEWPASSWD part of an OLDPASSWD that's part of a resetpassword.  That does not make any sort of semantic sense.  GETs should not be used to save data.

You should be doing something like this:

```
POST https://www.example.com/user/joe/resetpassword/
{oldpasswd:[data], newpasswd:[data]}
```

POST because you are writing data, and https because you don't want it sniffed.

(This is really the low-bar security.  The absolute minimum you should do.)

Comment: Wouldn't this mean hashing the passwords on the client-side? Is this recommended?

Comment: Note: this will not allow enforcing password (length, etc.) requirements. That may not be an issue in your case, though it is a frequent security practice, and sometime required by some entities.

Comment: @RowanFreeman Yeah, you're probably right.

Comment: @PaulDraper why not? what prevents you from checking on the server the constraints on the new password and returning an appropriate error? *edit* I assume that part refered to the use of password hashes, which have been edited since your comment

Comment: @StevenBurnap really, the topic author didn't say this is GET, and URL itself doesn't contain the HTTP method. I guessed either POST or PUT here, but neither is appropriate for other reasons, already described.

Comment: You're not creating a new record but updating an existing record (usually), so this should be PUT rather than POST.

Comment: I thought about the sniffing part. Anybody that can sniff the URL can also sniff the POST/PUT data, so there is no gain there.

Comment: @CamilStaps: It isn't that easy. [PUT vs POST in REST](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/630453/put-vs-post-in-rest)

Comment: This is not very RESTful. resetpassword is not a resource let alone sub-resource. However, `/user/joe/password` is a little better but not optimal.

Comment: @CamilStaps No, you cannot use `PUT`, because `PUT` is idempotent. But when the password has been changed from `secret` to `supersecret` sucessfully, then the same request will fail the second time, so `POST` is correct here. Of course, as @whirlwin said, this resource is not well named.

Comment: @StevenBurnap You should not be sending the old password in the body. Use an Authorization header to convey existing credentials.

Comment: @RowanFreeman, no. You're using HTTPS to prevent MITM attacks. Hashing is so that the server doesn't actually store the password. Hashing client side doesn't help that much. It'll prevent a malicious user from trying the password on other sites, but they'll be able to log into your site, obviously, by just sending that hash as if it was the password. To prevent this, you use HTTPS, which negates the use for hashing client side entirely. Also, hashing client side prevents those with JS disabled from logging in. The truly security minded will want to disable JS whenever possible.

Answer (score 64):

The proposed scheme has issues in several areas.

**Security**

URL paths are frequently logged; putting unhashed passwords in the path is poor practice.

**HTTP**

Authentication/authorization information should appear in the Authorization header. Or potentially, for browser-based stuff, the Cookie header.

**REST**

Verbs such as `resetpassword` in your URL are generally a clear sign of a non-representational state transfer paradigm. A URL should represent a resource. What does it mean to GET `resetpassword`? Or DELETE?

**API**

This scheme requires always knowing the previous password. You will probably want to allow for more cases; e.g. the password is lost.

---

You could use [Basic or Digest authentication](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2617), which is are well understood schemes.

```
PUT /user/joe/password HTTP/1.0
Authorization: Basic QWxhZGRpbjpvcGVuIHNlc2FtZQ==
Content-Type: text/plain
Host: www.example.com

NEWPASSWD
```

It doesn't put ultra-sensitive information in the path, and it follows HTTP and REST conventions.

If you needed to allow for some other mode of authorization (e.g. some token sent through a verified channel to reset the password), you can simply use a different Authorization header without having to change anything else.

Answer (score 5):

The problem is to avoid plain text passwords in your requests.
There are two options to fulfill the restful webservice requirements.

**1. Client side hashing**

- I'll guess you are storing your passwords like e. g. hash(password+salt)
- You can hash the new password with a salt on the client side
- That means: Create a new salt on the client side, create a hash e. g. hash(newPassword+newSalt)
- Send the new created hash plus the salt to your restful webservice
- Send the old password also as hash(oldPassword+oldSalt)

**2. Encryption**

- Create a "one time key" (otk) resource for a user like /otk/john
- This resource returns an secure random unique one time key, e. g. kbDlJbmNmQ0Y0SmRHZC9GaWtRMW0ycVJpYzhMcVNZTWlMUXN6ZWxLdTZESFRs and a unique ID e. g. 95648915125
- Your restful webservice has to store this random otk for the next secure communication with the ID 95648915125
- Encrypt your new and old password with the otk e. g. AES (for security reasons you should use two separate otks for the old and new password)
- Send the encrypted passwords to your change password resource with the ID 95648915125
- One otk and ID combination is allowed to work once only, so you have to deleted that combination after chaning the password
- Possible better option: Send the current/old password by Basic-Auth.

**Note:** HTTPS is required for both options!

Comment: Why would I double-encrypt (your encryption scheme with the OTK, and HTTPS) the password exchange? What's the attack vector here that is not covered by HTTPS?

Comment: The only purpose is to avoid possible server logs. A HTTP request body (for example with a plaintext new password) can also be logged although HTTPS is used. Other possible attack is the usage of a self-signed certificate which is especially used for internal purposes.

Answer (score 4):

Apart from security, the problem with this is that it isn't a very RESTful approach.

`OLDPASSWD` and `NEWPASSWD` don't stand for anything in your resource hierarchy and even worse, the operation isn't idempotent.

So you can only use `POST` as your verb, and you should not include the two passwords in your resource path.

Comment: You're not creating a new record but updating an existing record (usually), so this should be PUT rather than POST.

Comment: @CamilStaps If it was just setting the password, it could be. But since presumably the old password needs to be verified too, it makes the operation non-idempotent, and thus `PUT` is disqualified as a verb. It could be rejigged to work with `PUT` but in its current form it doesn't.

Comment: OLDPASSWD is authentication info and shouldn't be in the URL at all.

Comment: Not necessarily, it is common practice to explicitly ask for the old password on top of authentication.

Answer (score 3):

What are the features of a password-reset operation?

1. It change something.
2. There is a value that it is set to.
3. Only some people are allowed to do it (the user, an admin, or either, perhaps with different rules as to how either can do so).

Point 1 here means you cannot use GET, you must either POST something representing the password-change operation to a URI representing a resource that handles password changes, or PUT something representing the new password to a URI representing the password or representing something (e.g. the user) of which that password is a feature.

Generally we'd POST, not least because it can be awkward PUTting something we can't later GET and of course we can't GET the password.

Point 2 therefore will be data representing the new password, in what is POSTed.

Point 3 means we'll need to authorise the request, which means that if the user is the current user we'll need the current password to be proven to us (though not necessarily receive the current password, if e.g. a hash-based challenge was used to prove knowledge of it without sending it).

The URI should therefore be something like `<http://example.net/changeCurrentUserPassword>` or `<http://example.net/users/joe/changePassword>`.

We might decide that we want to receive the current password in the POST data as well as in the general authorisation mechanism being used.